# Core Data - Limiting number of saved objects

Tags: core-data, stack

Is there way to limit the number of saved objects in coredata like stack, where the last objects are automatically deleted?

Comment: Not enough detail; please edit the description to explain what "coredata like stack" means.

Comment: You want a stack or a LRU array?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is something you would need to implement in code.  You can, just before you call `-save:` on the `NSManagedObjectContext` query the `NSManagedObjectContext` for how many objects are going to be inserted and perform your custom logic at that point.